# R: how to get row and column names of the true elements of a matrix?

Tags: r

I have a logical matrix `x` with named rows ('a' and 'b') and named columns ('10', '20', '30', '40'). Let's say, this:

```
   10   20   30   40  
a  T    F    T    F  
b  F    T    F    T  

structure(c(TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE),
.Dim = c(2L, 4L), .Dimnames = list(c("a", "b"), c("10", "20", "30", "40")))
```

Is there a short way to get a table that would list names of rows and columns where I have true values? That is, I want to get the following table:

```
a  10, 30
b  20, 40
```

Something similar can be obtained by `which(x, arr.ind = T)`, which produces

```
  row col
a   1   1
b   2   2
a   1   3
b   2   4
```

But I really want to get the first table.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can directly use `apply`.

```
apply(
  x, 1, 
  function(u) paste( names(which(u)), collapse="," ) 
)
```

Comment: +1: `t(t(apply(m, 1, function(u) paste( names(which(u)), collapse=", " ))))` is even closer to the requested outcome and there are further tweaks

Answer (score 2):

You didn't specify this, but your desired output will require that we assume that the result is in fact rectangular. Namely, that we don't get 3 column names for a and only 2 column names for b.

I think this should get you started, at least:

```
m <- structure(c(TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE),
.Dim = c(2L, 4L), .Dimnames = list(c("a", "b"), c("10", "20", "30", "40")))

rr <- rownames(m)[row(m)[which(m)]]
cc <- colnames(m)[col(m)[which(m)]]

dd <- data.frame(rr = rr,cc = cc)
dd
```

which returns the information you want, but in a safer "long" format, which won't choke on the non-rectangular case. Once there, you could re-organize it as you specified like this:

```
library(plyr)
ddply(dd,.(rr),function(x){ x$cc })
```

but frankly that last bit I find really ugly, and I wouldn't be surprised if a better solution pops up if you wait a bit.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the fact that `table` objects are converted to "long" format data frames by `as.data.frame()`:

```
# Create matrix of interest 
mat <- structure(c(TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE), .Dim = c(2L, 4L), .Dimnames = list(c("a", "b"), c("10", "20", "30", "40")))

# Convert to table, then to long data.frame
df <- mat %>% as.table %>% as.data.frame(., stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

The resulting `df` is the following:

```
  Var1 Var2  Freq
1    a   10  TRUE
2    b   10 FALSE
3    a   20 FALSE
4    b   20  TRUE
5    a   30  TRUE
6    b   30 FALSE
7    a   40 FALSE
8    b   40  TRUE
```

Which you can then index to only keep `TRUE` rows:

```
df <- df[df$Freq,1:2] %>% sort
df
      Var1 Var2
    1    a   10
    5    a   30
    4    b   20
    8    b   40
```

You can use `dplyr` to convert this into exactly the table you want:

```
library(plyr)
ddply(df, "Var1", function(x) x$Var2)
  Var1 V1 V2
1    a 10 30
2    b 20 40
```