# Add multiple columns (TRUE/FALSE/NA) based on (not)matching a string with multiple-choice selections

Tags: r, data-cleaning

**Scenario**: Suvery tools often put multiple choice questions’s answers as a single value with concatenated strings: If asking which programming languages from a list people use, they will generate *"C;Python;R"* if they selected these options; all of these values in a single columns representing this multiple choice question – but that is hard to work with.

**Example data set**: [Stack Overflow Survey](https://insights.stackoverflow.com/survey), 2003, file `survey_results_public.csv` e.g. column `$LanguageHaveWorkedWith`

**Goal**: Based on the column holding the strings with the selected answers and a list of possible answers, I try to…

- Generate a column for each of the possible answers, e.g. `ProgLang_C`, `ProgLang_Java`…
- For e.g. *"C;Python;R"* the column `ProgLang_C` is *TRUE*, for `ProgLang_Java` it is *FALSE*; If there is *NA,* all values are *NA*, too (and not false) (so what I want is is what [str_detect](https://stringr.tidyverse.org/reference/str_detect.html) does)
- The code should work with piping the dataframe; tidyverse preferred, but not essential

resulting dataframe example (not using the example dataset’s column names for brevity)

| lang | lang_java | lang_C | lang_python | lang… |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| "C; python" | FALSE | TRUE | TRUE | … |
| … | … | … | … | … |

**Notes**:

- Seems to be the inverse operation to ["how to create a list column of column names where column values are TRUE"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66250764/how-to-create-a-list-column-of-column-names-where-column-values-are-true)

Comment: my solution, in the end was this: 

https://gist.github.com/jdittrich/f80a3ebbb18ff993fd22fd1199b8d40b

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this by splitting the string and reframing it in the long direction by observation number.  Then, you could pivot the language variable wider filling in missing values with `FALSE`.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
library(tidyr)
dat <- data.frame(lang = c("C;python", "R;python", "R;C;python"))
dat %>% 
  mutate(obs = row_number()) %>% 
  group_by(obs) %>% 
  reframe(lang_orig = lang, lang = c(str_split(lang, pattern=";", simplify=TRUE))) %>% 
  mutate(exist = TRUE) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = lang, names_prefix = "lang_", values_from= exist, values_fill = FALSE)
#> # A tibble: 3 × 5
#>     obs lang_orig  lang_C lang_python lang_R
#>   <int> <chr>      <lgl>  <lgl>       <lgl> 
#> 1     1 C;python   TRUE   TRUE        FALSE 
#> 2     2 R;python   FALSE  TRUE        TRUE  
#> 3     3 R;C;python TRUE   TRUE        TRUE
```

<sup>Created on 2024-01-17 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>